# SQL Server service shutdown due to 'bad?' SSL cert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-server

This morning it transpired that SQL Server 2012 service running on Win2012 had shut itself down.  When I logged in as the server admin and tried to access SSMS, after entering my credentials I got the 'transport' error.  On checking Windows Services, both SQL Server and Agent were stopped.  I tried to start them, but got a timeout error.

The SQL event log contains this entry:

> The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL
> connection. It returned the following error: 0x8009030d. Check
> certificates to make sure they are valid.

The Windows event logs contain these entries:

> Log Name: Application
>
> Source: MSSQLSERVER
>
> Date: 14/03/2013 09:01:40
>
> Description: Unable to load user-specified
> certificate [Cert Hash(sha1)
> "A1CF6EE1C352B7A185950EB400013269759C24BD"]. The server will not
> accept a connection. You should verify that the certificate is
> correctly installed. See "Configuring Certificate for Use by SSL" in
> Books Online.
>
> Description: TDSSNIClient initialization failed
> with error 0x80092004, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize
> SSL support. Cannot find object or property.
>
> Description: TDSSNIClient initialization failed
> with error 0x80092004, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed
> with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. Cannot find
> object or property.
>
> Description: Could not start the network library
> because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the
> cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error
> log.
>
> Description: SQL Server could not spawn
> FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and
> the Windows event logs for information about possible related
> problems.

The following procedure fixed the problem:

1. Start > SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (Properties)
3. Uncheck General > Force Encryption
4. Start > Services > Start MSSQLSERVER service

### Update:

The above only fixed the problem until the next reboot, whereby it happened again.  Apparently the SSL certificate needs permissions to be read by SQL2012, but I daren't keep rebooting until this gets fixed, so am accessing via RDC now instead of SSMS over SSL.

Comment: Certificate subject is "elea1.memset.net" and the FDQN of SQL Server is "elea1" (well that's what's at the top of the Object Explorer - please advise if I can get more info elsewhere).  We've never connected to SSMS externally even though it was set up to use SSL.

Comment: Is SQL host machine joined to `memset.net` domain? Had the certificate worked previously or it never worked?

Comment: BTW, SQL will not 'shut itself down' on a  cert issue. It won't start. So probably there was a restart involved, eg. a overnight patch was applied and required a restart. The event log will show this.

Comment: Yes this is looking like what's happened.  For info, the option to force encryption was set two months ago, with a fresh self-signed cert applied to the next dialog option.  There was never a problem until this morning, so perhaps it never worked and we weren't aware until today...?

Comment: This blog post http://thesqldude.com/2011/08/03/sql-server-service-does-not-start-after-enabling-ssl-encryption/ mentions adding the SQL Server user group account to the cert's permission list, however, it doesn't like the instructions are quite valid for Win2012 as I don't see that user group in my options.  My SQL Server runs under the NT Service\MSSQLSERVER account, so perhaps I should give that read-permissions on the certificate under the 'Private Keys' option?

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 the deployment security model has changed to use [Managed Service  Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#New_Accounts)

Comment: So is it possible to give an MSA access to a certificate?

Comment: In addition to the stuff that Remus mentioned I can see this happening if the cryptography service had crashed. Does rebooting the server fix the problem?

Comment: No.  Rebooting actually caused the problem as at this point the SSL data could not be read and SQL Server refused to start.  I actually stopped using this SSL cert so never properly resolved the problem, although I do see that permission needs to be given on the cert for the SSL engine to read it, however, without detailed instructions for Win2012 I'm not brave enough to try it.  I can't afford to have SQL shut down in case it fails :-\

Answer (score 4):

There are applications out there that change the ACLs on the machine keyset container folder. When this occurs, legitimate keyset users loose access to these keysets. See [KB 278381: Default permissions for the MachineKeys folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278381) for the correct permission set.

If you want absolute confirmation, see [BUG: You cannot enable encryption by using a certificate when SQL Server 2005 is running under the Network Service account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900495) for a 'workaround' (it involves compiling a C++ app that will reset the ACLs properly...). But you can simply set the ACLs according to mentioned KB278381 and see if the problem dissapear.

More related KBs:

- [Peer-to-Peer Framework APIs return a "PEER_E_NO_KEY_ACCESS" error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817754)
- [How to troubleshoot the Data Protection API (DPAPI)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309408)
- [Error message when you use Service Broker or database mirroring to connect to an instance of SQL Server 2005: "Connection handshake failed"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912412)

I am yet to find *which* application changes the ACLs. My money is on some antivirus apps. Don't ask me how I know about all this random pieces of disparate infos...

Answer (score 2):

I used a solution mentioned [here](https://thesqldude.com/2011/08/03/sql-server-service-does-not-start-after-enabling-ssl-encryption/). It worked for me.

1. Check the SQL Server Service Account name.
2. Check and verify the Certificate name. (It is configured in SQL Server Configuration Manager --> SQL Server Network Configuration --> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER --> Right CLick here and go to Properties --> In 'Certificate' tab, you can see a Certificate name.)
3. Go to 'RUN', type 'MMC', and press 'Enter'.
4. Go to 'File' --> Add/Remove Snap-in.
5. Select 'Certificate' and click on the 'Add' button. Select appropriate options (from 'My User Account / Service Account / Computer Account').
6. Click on the 'OK' button on the 'Add or Remove Snap-ins' window screen.
7. On the 'Console1' window, go to the 'Console Root' option.
8. Expand 'Certificates' --> Personnel --> Certificates.

Here you will see the list of certificates.

9. Go to the certificate (which is configured in Step 2)
10. Right-click on that and go to 'All Tasks' --> Manage Private Keys...
11. Click on the 'Add' button and add the SQL Service Account here (from Step 1). Give all permission to this account.
12. Now, try to start the SQL Services.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation similar to this.  Even though the SQL Server Configuration Manager showed that Force Encryption was "No" and the certificate page was clear, I continued to get this error and was unable to start the service at all.

In the registry (for my installation):

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib

The Certificate String had the value equal to the hash in the error message.  Removing that value worked for me.